# Aspose upgrade - Missing properties

Tags: vb.net, upgrade, aspose, aspose.words

We are trying to upgrade Aspose and found that Aspose.Words.Document.MailMerge.**MergeField** and **MergeFieldEventArgs** is missing in newer version.

Can some one help me with a replacement of this property/method?

```
Dim doc As Document = New Aspose.Words.Document(fileName)
AddHandler doc.MailMerge.MergeField, AddressOf HandleMergeField


Public Sub HandleMergeField(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MergeFieldEventArgs)
    'Do something
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Aspose.Words.MailMerging** namespace contains classes of mail merge reporting engine. Please remove old mail merge namespace from your application and add Aspose.Words.MailMerging namespace. You need to implement IFieldMergingCallback interface to achieve your requirement. Please check following code example.

```
Public Sub MailMergeInsertHtml()
    Dim doc As New Document(MyDir & "MailMerge.doc")

    ' Add a handler for the MergeField event.
    doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = New HandleMergeField()


    ' Execute mail merge.
    doc.MailMerge.Execute(New String() { "fieldname" }, New String() { "field value" })

    ' Save resulting document with a new name.
    doc.Save(MyDir & "MailMergeOut.doc")
End Sub

Private Class HandleMergeField
    Implements IFieldMergingCallback
    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is called when merge field is actually merged with data in the document.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub IFieldMergingCallback_FieldMerging(ByVal e As FieldMergingArgs) Implements IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging
         '' Your code
    End Sub

    Private Sub ImageFieldMerging(ByVal e As ImageFieldMergingArgs) Implements IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging
        ' Do nothing.
    End Sub
End Class
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.